# ES6 Classes implement indexer like arrays

Tags: ecmascript-6

I want to implement indexer to get elements from data property with index as JavaScript arrays. I heard about ES6 proxies but I couldn't implement it to my class. Is it possible now or should I wait more to come with ES7.

```
class Polygon {
    constructor() {
        this.data = new Set(arguments)
    }

    [Symbol.iterator](){
        return this.data[Symbol.iterator]()
    }

    add(vertex){
        this.data.add(vertex)
    }

    remove(vertex){
        this.data.delete(vertex)
    }

    get perimeter(){

    }

    get area(){

    }
}

let poly = new Polygon()
let first_vertex = poly[0]
```

Comment: why don't you just subclass array?

Comment: @the8472 That may not work correctly if using a transpiler. Also assignment would allow duplicate values, unlike the usage of `Set` in the question.

Comment: I assumed the example was just a toy example, because it would be fairly inefficient to actually do counted iteration over a set to get the Nth element

Comment: @the8472 Fair point. Agreed though that subclassing an Array is now a feasible option

Answer (score 21):

AFAIK there is no proposal for something like "indexing" into arbitrary objects, so yes, you would have to go with proxies.

<del>I couldn't really test this since no environment seems to support both classes and proxies, but in theory,</del> you'd have to return the new proxied object from the constructor. Tested in Chrome v52.

Example:

```
class Test {
  constructor(data) {
    let self = this;
    this.data = data;
    this.foo = 'bar';

    return new Proxy(this, {
      get(target, prop) {
        if (Number(prop) == prop && !(prop in target)) {
          return self.data[prop];
        }
        return target[prop];
      }
    });
  }
}

var test = new Test([1,2,3]);
console.log(test[0]); // should log 1
console.log(test.foo); // should log 'bar'
```

Comment: Yes. this is the behaviour that i want. Do you know any platform that supports es6 proxies?

Comment: Firefox seems to support Proxies but not `class` syntax. You can try it with normal constructor functions though.

Comment: I tested your example code with firefox nightly and it works as expected. Now wish to see this support in node.js as soon as possible. Thanks @FelixKling

Comment: target could be used in place of self I think, they show strict equality target === self