# Dynamic Getters/Setters with ES6 Classes

Tags: dynamic, proxy, ecmascript-6, getter-setter

I've been searching the web and found some solutions but not an easy to implement solution for dynamic setters in an ES6 Class.

What I'd like is to have is a dynamic setter inside my class so that when I add any possible property from the outside, a certain operation will occur on that property. I've read on Proxies and that does seem to be the reasonable solution for this. However, I wasn't able to understand how to correctly implement it and would like your guys' input on this.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/32622970/218196 for an example how it *could* be done. tl;dr: Apply the proxy to the newly created instance in the constructor.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
let property_one = 'one';
let property_two = 'two';

/**
 * ConfigurationClass class.
 */
class ConfigurationClass
{

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * Create instance.
     */
    constructor(config = {
        'property_one' : property_one,
        'property_two' : property_two,
    })
    {
        this.__proto__ = new Proxy(config, {
            get: (container, property)        => (property in container) ? container[property] : undefined,
            set: (container, property, value) => (container[property] = value) ? true : true
        });
    }

};

let configurationClass = new ConfigurationClass();

console.log(configurationClass.property_one);   // one
console.log(configurationClass.property_two);   // two
console.log(configurationClass.property_three); // undefined
```